# ANDROID: Load view for activity asynchronously

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a custom `view class` that I want to set for my `activity`. However it's initiation is very long (Most of the code, such as loading bitmaps is placed in constructor). Therefore, I want to show the user a preloader before setting the `View`.

I've tried setting the loading screen first and launching the `view` on a different thread using asynctask and handlers, though without any luck. The first gives me `can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare()` and the other one just executes code line by line.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, any ideas how to divide the loading process, e.g.:
1. set `loading screen`.
2. load `view class` on the background (instantiate).
3. set the `view class` in place of the `loading screen`.

Thanks

***UPDATE***

```
public MainMenuView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    System.gc();

    this.context = context;

    sh = new SharedHelper(context);
    am = context.getAssets();

    sp = new SoundHelper(context, 
            SoundHelper.CLICK,
            SoundHelper.MAIN_MELODY
            );

    screenWH = Helper.getScreenDimensions(context);
    bg = new Background(screenWH, am);
    scaleAmount = bg.scaleAmount();
    scaleAmount = scaleAmount * 0.9f;

    strings = Helper.getStrings((int)sh.getOption(Option.LANGUAGE), new DBHelper(context));

    mainTitle = Helper.scaleBMP(Helper.assetImage(am, "Main/title.png"), scaleAmount);
    mainTitleM.postTranslate(bg.getMargins()[0], -10);

    /**
     * Load cloud-like buttons
     * */

    float top = 0.03f * screenWH[1];
    float left = bg.getMargins()[0] + mainTitle.getWidth();
    MainButton repeat = new MainButton("Main/Buttons/repeat_on.png", "Main/Buttons/repeat.png", am, scaleAmount);
    repeat.setPosition(left, top);
    repeat.setType(Helper.REPEAT);
    btns.add(repeat);

    left += 0.3f * repeat.getBMP().getWidth();
    top += repeat.getBMP().getHeight();
    MainButton test = new MainButton("Main/Buttons/test_on.png", "Main/Buttons/test.png", am, scaleAmount);
    test.setPosition(left, top);
    test.setType(Helper.TEST);
    btns.add(test);

    left -= 0.7f * test.getBMP().getWidth();
    top += 0.5f * test.getBMP().getHeight();

    MainButton learn = new MainButton("Main/Buttons/learn_on.png", "Main/Buttons/learn.png", am, scaleAmount);
    learn.setPosition(left, top);
    learn.setType(Helper.LEARN);
    btns.add(learn);

    /**
     * Main control buttons
     * */

    left = 5;
    top = bg.getTopMargin();
    buttonClass parent = new buttonClass("Buttons/parents control.png", am, scaleAmount, Helper.PARENTS);
    parent.setPosition(left, top);
    btns.add(parent);

    top += parent.getBMP().getHeight() + 2;
    buttonClass facebook = new buttonClass("Buttons/facebook.png", am, scaleAmount, Helper.FACEBOOK);
    facebook.setPosition(left, top);
    btns.add(facebook);

    top += facebook.getBMP().getHeight() + 2;
    buttonClass share = new buttonClass("Buttons/share.png", am, scaleAmount, Helper.SHARE);
    share.setPosition(left, top);
    btns.add(share);

    top += share.getBMP().getHeight() + 2;
    buttonClass pay = new buttonClass("Buttons/pay.png", am, scaleAmount, Helper.PAY);
    pay.setPosition(left, top);
    btns.add(pay);

    /**
     * Sprites
     * */

    float widthsix = 0;
    float widthasix = 0;
    float highest = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=11; i++){
        mainSprite spr = new mainSprite(i, context, scaleAmount);
        if(i <= 6){
            widthsix += spr.getBMP().getWidth();
        }
        else{
            widthasix += spr.getBMP().getWidth();
        }
        if(i == 9){
            highest = spr.getBMP().getHeight();
        }
        sprites.add(spr);
    }
    float[] margins = bg.getMargins();
    left = margins[0] + (margins[2] - margins[0] - widthsix) / 2;
    float leftA = margins[0] + (margins[2] - margins[0] - widthasix) / 2;
    top = screenWH[1] - highest;



    float angle = 0;
    float offset = 0.05f * screenWH[1];
    float angle_step = 30.0f;
    int i = 1;
    float topA = 0;
    for(mainSprite s : sprites){
        float top_mod = top - s.getBMP().getHeight() + (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * offset - offset;
        s.setPosition(left, top_mod);

        left += s.getBMP().getWidth();
        angle += angle_step;
        if(i == 3){
            topA = screenWH[1];
        }
        if(i == 6){
            top = topA;
            left = leftA;
            angle_step = 36f;
            angle = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    sp.playSound(SoundHelper.MAIN_MELODY);

    addDialog();
    /**
     * start animation
     * */
    currentSpr = 8;
    sprites.get(currentSpr).start();
    handle.postDelayed(runAnimation, 5000);

}

public void loadMain(){
    screenWH = Helper.getScreenDimensions(context);

    bg = new Background(screenWH, am);
    scaleAmount = bg.scaleAmount();
    scaleAmount = scaleAmount * 0.9f;

    strings = Helper.getStrings((int)sh.getOption(Option.LANGUAGE), new DBHelper(context));

    mainTitle = Helper.scaleBMP(Helper.assetImage(am, "Main/title.png"), scaleAmount);
    mainTitleM.postTranslate(bg.getMargins()[0], -10);

    /**
     * Load cloud-like buttons
     * */

    float top = 0.03f * screenWH[1];
    float left = bg.getMargins()[0] + mainTitle.getWidth();
    MainButton repeat = new MainButton("Main/Buttons/repeat_on.png", "Main/Buttons/repeat.png", am, scaleAmount);
    repeat.setPosition(left, top);
    repeat.setType(Helper.REPEAT);
    btns.add(repeat);

    left += 0.3f * repeat.getBMP().getWidth();
    top += repeat.getBMP().getHeight();
    MainButton test = new MainButton("Main/Buttons/test_on.png", "Main/Buttons/test.png", am, scaleAmount);
    test.setPosition(left, top);
    test.setType(Helper.TEST);
    btns.add(test);

    left -= 0.7f * test.getBMP().getWidth();
    top += 0.5f * test.getBMP().getHeight();

    MainButton learn = new MainButton("Main/Buttons/learn_on.png", "Main/Buttons/learn.png", am, scaleAmount);
    learn.setPosition(left, top);
    learn.setType(Helper.LEARN);
    btns.add(learn);

    /**
     * Main control buttons
     * */

    left = 5;
    top = bg.getTopMargin();
    buttonClass parent = new buttonClass("Buttons/parents control.png", am, scaleAmount, Helper.PARENTS);
    parent.setPosition(left, top);
    btns.add(parent);

    top += parent.getBMP().getHeight() + 2;
    buttonClass facebook = new buttonClass("Buttons/facebook.png", am, scaleAmount, Helper.FACEBOOK);
    facebook.setPosition(left, top);
    btns.add(facebook);

    top += facebook.getBMP().getHeight() + 2;
    buttonClass share = new buttonClass("Buttons/share.png", am, scaleAmount, Helper.SHARE);
    share.setPosition(left, top);
    btns.add(share);

    top += share.getBMP().getHeight() + 2;
    buttonClass pay = new buttonClass("Buttons/pay.png", am, scaleAmount, Helper.PAY);
    pay.setPosition(left, top);
    btns.add(pay);

    /**
     * Sprites
     * */

    float widthsix = 0;
    float widthasix = 0;
    float highest = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=11; i++){
        mainSprite spr = new mainSprite(i, context, scaleAmount);
        if(i <= 6){
            widthsix += spr.getBMP().getWidth();
        }
        else{
            widthasix += spr.getBMP().getWidth();
        }
        if(i == 9){
            highest = spr.getBMP().getHeight();
        }
        sprites.add(spr);
    }
    float[] margins = bg.getMargins();
    left = margins[0] + (margins[2] - margins[0] - widthsix) / 2;
    float leftA = margins[0] + (margins[2] - margins[0] - widthasix) / 2;
    top = screenWH[1] - highest;



    float angle = 0;
    float offset = 0.05f * screenWH[1];
    float angle_step = 30.0f;
    int i = 1;
    float topA = 0;
    for(mainSprite s : sprites){
        float top_mod = top - s.getBMP().getHeight() + (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * offset - offset;
        s.setPosition(left, top_mod);

        left += s.getBMP().getWidth();
        angle += angle_step;
        if(i == 3){
            topA = screenWH[1];
        }
        if(i == 6){
            top = topA;
            left = leftA;
            angle_step = 36f;
            angle = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    sp.playSound(SoundHelper.MAIN_MELODY);

    addDialog();
    /**
     * start animation
     * */
    currentSpr = 8;
    sprites.get(currentSpr).start();
    //handle.postDelayed(runAnimation, 5000);
}
```

I'm loading the view in the onCreate method of Activity

```
 new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
setContentView(new CustomView(context));
}
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code? :)

Comment: @t0mm13b well, it's messy. But I can't figure out how to load the view on a different thread and then feed it to Activity

Comment: @t0mm13b as I've stated above AsyncTask gives me the aobve mentioned error `can't create handler inside thread...`

Comment: Cross threading - `can't create handler inside thread` - you're setting a view *inside* the thread which is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that loads all the bitmaps and stuff inside the `AsyncTask` instead of doing it in the constructor. Do this from the `onCreate` activity method.

You can then use the `onProgressUpdate` callback of the `AsyncTask` to inform of progress (e.g. a loading progress bar). For example, you can use `ProgresBar.setMax` to set it to the number of items to load, pass that to the progress callback as you load items via `publishProgress`, then call `ProgressBar.setProgress` with that value.

As you load the items, you can add these to an `Assets` class. This can be passed back via the `onPostExecute` callback method which you can then assign to a member variable in your activity.

You can then either have the layout of the activity look like:

```
LinearLayout
    RelativeLayout [id=load_screen, background=loading_bg]
        ProgressBar [id=loading_progress]
    RelativeLayout [id=main, visibility=hidden]
        ...
```

then call `findViewById(R.id.load_screen).setVisible(View.GONE)` to hide the load screen and `findViewById(R.id.load_screen).setVisible(View.VISIBLE)`

Alternatively, you can load your replacement view (via the `LayoutInflater.inflate` call) and then call `setContentView` on it. When the `inflate` call returns, the view is fully loaded, so you can do all the handler setup here.

The layout loading or visibility switch will also happen in the `onPostExecute` method of the `AsyncTask`.